# Excel and rather complex "SUM IF" with multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two sheets of data, the original being in sheet data, and the new one in sheet1 (that references to original data, to sheet luonnos). To put it simply, I have multiple species occurences from same "plots", and the data from the same plot should be summed/combined. Unfortunately I didn't collect this data by myself, and hence each species occurence is recorded on a new row, even if they existed on the same plot.

In column H I have the plot number. If the plot numbers are the same, then the species occurences (0-1 data, from columns J forward) should be summed. If the plot number is text rather than a number, then excel should just return the original value from data sheet.

Please see the pic attached for more clarification.

For now, I've started with this, but maybe I should try completely different kind of approach? Now it compares the plot number to the plot number on the next row, and if they match, then it sums up the species occurrence in a given column.

`=(IF(data!$H29=data!$H30,SUM(data!J29,data!J30),data!J29))`

1. I need to include another condition, that value in column H (plot number) has to be a number, and if the numbers match, then sum up species occurences. I tried to include AND(ISNUMBER() -kind of clause, but with little success.
2. There may be up to 5 rows from the same plot. After finding that the next row has the same sample number, it should also check if the next row matches too.

Eventually, for example in a case of 5 rows of the same plot, I would like to get either 5 rows with identical data (and then remove the "duplicate" rows, which I guess is rather easy), OR have only one row of the summed up data with the rest staying blank. Anyhow I can worry about this later on.

I know this might be a tedious question I'm asking, and I'm really grateful if you could just push me onto the right direction! Any little piece of help is highly appreciated.

[image: pic of the data and some explanation]

Comment: you could start with unpivot-ing your data (there are plenty of guidance on that already), then it'll be easy to make your final table with a new pivot table based on your unpivoted data.

Comment: Hi! Actually it isn't pivoted, the very first raw data I obtained was. In it, the species occurences were in a form that wouldn't have been suitable to ordination analysis, hence I have now converted the species to columns and species data to 0-1 data.

I did make a pivot table of this data here too, but it doesn't help that much - there's altogether 6700+ rows of data from 80 different sites, and in each site, there's 2-10 plots with multiple species occurences. In each site, the plot numbering starts from 1. So, I still have hundreds of rows where the sp. data needs to be summed.